# SharePoint Online - Autocomplete fields from Excel Sheet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I working on a solution here which may or may not be possible with SharePoint Online (365)

I have a large excel list (975 lines) of students containing columns: student ID, Surname, First Name, Full Name, Year Level, Form, House, SubSchool

What is requested here is to import the spreadsheet into SharePoint which can be done, then create a new document set content type called "Student" containing all columns names from the spreadsheet. After this a new document library is created, added content type to library and this is where I get stuck... what is requested is the following;

1. Be able to select a students name either typing or using a people picker when creating a new document set (student), and all the other fields listed above are populated automatically FROM the spreadsheet list that was imported into SharePoint previously.

The other half of this is that they would like to update this spreadsheet every year so that the data in the speadsheet will change and therefore the information in SharePoint will change as well.

Has any one tried to achieve anything like this before in SharePoint online?

Cheers